# Are child Classes equivalent to their racine class from type of object perspective?

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass, super

I've created 3 abstract classes:

class Article : mother Class

```
public abstract class Article{
    //myPrivate Var Declarations
    public Article(long reference, String title, float price, int quantity){
        this.reference  =   reference;
        this.title      =   title;
        this.price      =   price;
        this.quantity   =   quantity;
    }
}
```

class Electromenager : a child of Article

```
public abstract class Electromenager extends Article{
    //myVar declarations 
    public Electromenager(long reference, String title, float price, int quantity, int power, String model) {
        super(reference, title, price, quantity);
        this.power  = power;
        this.model  = model;
    }
}
```

Class Alimentaire: another child of Article

```
public abstract class Alimentaire extends Article{
    private int expire;
    public Alimentaire(long reference, String title, float price, int quantity,int expire){
        super(reference, title, price, quantity);
        this.expire = expire;
    }
}
```

Let's just suppose that these classes must be abstract, so basically in the main class, I can't instantiate directly their objects to do so we need to do some basic extends..:

```
class TV extends Electromenager {
    public TV(long reference, String title, float price, int quantity, int power, String model){
        super(reference,title,price,quantity,power,model);
    }
}
class EnergyDrink extends alimentaire {
    public EnergyDrink(long reference, String title, float price, int quantity,int expire){
        super(reference,title,price,quantity,expire);
    }
}
```

So here where my confusion start to occur ! when writing this in the main():

```
Article art         = new TV (145278, "OLED TV", 1000 , 1 ,220, "LG");
EnergyDrink art2    = new EnergyDrink (155278 , "Eau Miniral" , 6 , 10, 2020);
```

Surprisingly I'm getting zero error !!!! shouldn't I type:  :

```
TV art          = new TV (145278, "OLED TV", 1000 , 1 ,220, "LG");
//instead of
Article art     = new TV (145278, "OLED TV", 1000 , 1 ,220, "LG");
```

Why both writing are correct? And how does the Java compiler understand this?

Comment: `Article` is base class for `TV` so base class objects can hold reference to child class which are extended by base class

Comment: Why shouldn´t it compile? From your definition a `TV` is also an `Article`, so you are able to assign an instance of `TV` in a variable defined as `Article`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child classes have all the functionality of their base class.

By saying

```
Article art         = new TV (145278, "OLED TV", 1000 , 1 ,220, "LG");
```

you *declare* `art` as an Article object, which is not wrong. You won't be able to access TV-only functions without casting.
Anyway an new TV object is *created*. If you cast it:

```
TV tv         = (TV) art;
```

There won't be any problem and you can access all the TV functions.

To be more general, even

```
Object object = new TV (145278, "OLED TV", 1000 , 1 ,220, "LG");
```

would work.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that we can cast objects to get inclusive methods...
let's imagine that TV has a method called:

`changeModel( String model);`

This:

`Article art         = new TV (145278, "OLED TV", 1000 , 1 ,220, "LG");`

won't allow me to write: art.changeModel("QHD"); ? 

and one more question, what is Article art / Tv art / Object object ? .
does it mean that I declared a reference (kinda like a pointer ) to an object that I created in the memory using new operator ? 
why i can't for example write this:
` EnergyDrink art    =    new Tv(145278, "OLED TV", 1000 , 1 ,220  , "LG" ); `  ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to think of line `Article art = new TV (145278, "OLED TV", 1000 , 1 ,220, "LG");`

in two separate steps,

1. Creating an `Object` of type `TV` using `new` operator
2. Declaring a reference type variable `art` of type `Article` and assigning `TV` object created in step#1 to it

You are calling a valid constructor of type `TV`  in Step 1 and since `Article` is a parent of `TV` so assignment is valid too in step 2.